# Why rule isn't matching the largest input?

Tags: antlr4

I have the following grammar:

```
myg                : line+ EOF ;

line                : ( command params | for_loop ) NEWLINE;

for_loop : 'for' WORD INT 'do'  NEWLINE stmt_body;

stmt_body: line+ 'end';

params              : ( param | WHITESPACE)*;

param                : WORD | INT;

command             : WORD;

fragment LOWERCASE  : [a-z] ;
fragment UPPERCASE  : [A-Z] ;
fragment DIGIT : [0-9] ;

WORD                : (LOWERCASE | UPPERCASE | DIGIT | [_."'/\\-])+ (DIGIT)* ;
INT : DIGIT+ ;
WHITESPACE          : (' ' | '\t')+ ;
NEWLINE             : ('\r'? '\n' | '\r')+ ;
```

When trying the following:

```
>java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig Myg myg -tokens
command with parameter for 90 seconds
^Z
[@0,0:6='command',<WORD>,1:0]
[@1,7:7=' ',<WHITESPACE>,1:7]
[@2,8:11='with',<WORD>,1:8]
[@3,12:12=' ',<WHITESPACE>,1:12]
[@4,13:21='parameter',<WORD>,1:13]
[@5,22:22=' ',<WHITESPACE>,1:22]
[@6,23:25='for',<'for'>,1:23]
[@7,26:26=' ',<WHITESPACE>,1:26]
[@8,27:28='90',<WORD>,1:27]
[@9,29:29=' ',<WHITESPACE>,1:29]
[@10,30:36='seconds',<WORD>,1:30]
[@11,37:38='\r\n',<NEWLINE>,1:37]
[@12,39:38='<EOF>',<EOF>,2:0]
line 1:23 missing NEWLINE at 'for'
line 1:26 extraneous input ' ' expecting WORD
line 1:29 mismatched input ' ' expecting {WORD, INT, WHITESPACE, NEWLINE}
```

For a reason I don't understand, 'for' is matched as 'for' where my expectation is that the "command" rule should have matched the entire input line since a rule should match the largest input.

Or in other terms the command rule should have been greedy and matched the entire line.

Also for_loop is a parser rule(start with lower case) so why it hasn't been ignored during the production of the tokens?

Comment: Please show the definitions of your lexer rules. I imagine the reason that `WORD` doesn't match the entire line is that it can't (i.e. the entire line wouldn't fit `WORD`'s pattern).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `command` rule matches a single `WORD` token, so the question becomes why `WORD` doesn't match the whole line. And the answer to that is that `WORD` doesn't match spaces, so it could only match up to the first space, not the entire rule. But 'for' also matches up to the first space and literals take precedence when two rules produce a match of the same length.

> Also for_loop is a parser rule(start with lower case) so why it hasn't been ignored during the production of the tokens?

`for_loop` is a parser rule (and it is indeed ignored for lexing - you won't see any `for_loop` tokens in the output), but 'for' is not. All literals are lexer rules (otherwise they could never match).